# Query to get username from child table with specific condition

Tags: sql

I have a table `Admin` and a child table `AdminOfArea`. I want to get the user name from Table2 where username only have one Region not multiple which is Liverpool. in this case only A and B are according to this scenario.

Table 1 looks like

```
|Username |  UserType  |
|  abc    |  Admin     |
|   A     |  Admin     |
|  xyz    |  Admin     |
|   B     |  Admin     |
```

Table 2 looks like

```
|UserName  Region    |
| abc     Wales      |
| abc     Liverpool  |   
| abc     Westsussex |
| A       Liverpool  |
| xyz     Wales      |
| xyz     Liverpool  |
| xyz     Westsussex |
| B       Liverpool  |
```

Comment: I removed the incompatible database tags.  Only tag with the database you are really using.

Comment: I removed clutter...

Comment: Add some non-Admin UserTypes as well. And specify the expected result.

Comment: What have you tried? Show us your current query attempt.

Comment: "I want to" is not a question, it's a statement of your requirement. What specific problem are you facing? What did you research or try for yourself before asking for the free time of others to solve your problem? This is not going to need hugely complex SQL.

Answer (score 0):

Here is one method that should work in any database:

```
select t1.*, t2.region
from table1 t1 join
     (select t2.username, max(region) as region
      from table2 t2
      group by t2.username
      having count(*) = 1
     ) t2
     on t1.username = t2.username;
```

Comment: t2 as table alias twice... Not what I'd recommend.

Comment: @Sir Gordon Linoff, Dont you think the user only want the username with exactly 1 Region from table 2 only. So Only Counting region grouping by username will give us the desired result. I mean only inner query is sufficient.

Comment: @AnkitBajpai . . . In that case, just use the subquery.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to fetch the data only from the second table based on **region='Liverpool'** by excluding those username which have multiple region, you can go with following query.

```
SELECT username FROM adminofarea WHERE region='Liverpool' GROUP BY adminofarea.username HAVING COUNT(1) = 1
```

Comment: The user doesn't want to filter out the result based on region. He want the result where a user have only 1 region. Be it Liverpool or Chelsea. So your where cond is not needed in this case.

Answer (score 0):

```
Select Username,count(Region) FROM AdminOfArea
GROUP BY Username
```

Using Upper Query U will get Username along with total no of region that particular username have Example: *abc have 3.*

```
Select Username FROM AdminOfArea
GROUP BY Username
having count(Region) = 1
```

Using Having Clause we have separated those username who is associated with only 1 region